# About IOS UIScrollView Sliding automatic will bounce back

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

My app's UIScrollView Sliding automatic will bounce back,what can i do?
I do not want!

my code below:

```
- (void)initScrollView {
    // a page is the width of the scroll view 
        sv = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 96, 320, 300)];
        sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(sv.frame.size.width * 3, sv.frame.size.height* 2);
        sv.pagingEnabled = YES;
        sv.clipsToBounds = YES;
        sv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        sv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
        sv.scrollsToTop = NO;
        sv.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
        sv.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:sv];

        currentPage = 0;
        pageControl.numberOfPages = 3;
        pageControl.currentPage = 0;
        pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self createAllEmptyPagesForScrollView];
}
- (void)createAllEmptyPagesForScrollView {

    tapView1 = [[UIView alloc]init];
    tapView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tapView1.frame = CGRectMake(320*0, 0, 320, sv.frame.size.height);

    tapView2 = [[UIView alloc]init];
    tapView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tapView2.frame = CGRectMake(320*1, 0, 320, sv.frame.size.height);

    tapView3 = [[UIView alloc]init];
    tapView3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tapView3.frame = CGRectMake(320*2, 0, 320, sv.frame.size.height);

    [sv addSubview:tapView1];
    [sv addSubview:tapView2];
    [sv addSubview:tapView3];
}
```

Comment: UIScrollView has a "bounces" property, set it to no.

Comment: To nevan king: i use sv.bounces = NO; Problem the same!When I slide up automatically bounce back

Answer (score 0):

i konw why I slide up automatically bounce back,my code have problem!Not bove code!thanks everyone!